# Having trouble with choppy gradients for web page background image on some systems

Tags: css, html, background, gradient

Really not sure why this is occuring but with some systems the backround image gradient appears choppy and only half of it even appears, also some systems display the color so light is can barely even be seen especially those with lower resolution settings. Any ideas why this is occuring?

Here is the link to the page: http://www.kapacitive.com/Main_Page_Template.html I have it here just for testing purposes.

I also noticed that if I change the CSS positioning of the background to background-position:50% 50%; the issue of only having half the backround appear occurs on my main system.

I have a small touch screen Garmin device that has a web browser and with that device the background appears both choppy and only half appears, though I really didn't expect much from that device in the first place.

My secondary machine has a lower resolution display and with that system the background can barely be seen. This also occurs using an entirely different machine and display which has a lower resolution setting.

Maybe, I should just trash the background all together with all these damn bugs occuring, though in my opinion it does look better with the background.

If anyone wants to volunteer test the page using other devices and provide the results that would also be cool, I currently do not own any Apple devices.

Like I've stated any suggestions or ideas on resolving this issue would be great and even any insight about why this is occuring. I realize each machine is different but the differences in how this page is rendering between different machines is way too drastic in my opinion to be acceptable for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the color-depth of the machines viewing the background image. That nicely faded gradient relies on a LOT of colors, and on a screen with a limited palette, it's going to be choppy.

A work around would be to test the `pixelDepth`/`colorDepth` of visitors' screens, and to dynamically change the background image to something plainer if it is too low. Most browsers provide that information [via JavaScript] in the `screen` variable.

[window.screen.colorDepth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.colorDepth)

[window.screen.pixelDepth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.pixelDepth)

Comment: I look further into this. I just realized that even on my high res. monitor the gradient appears blocky it is just less apparent, I am now looking at the original photoshop file and it also appears to have the blocky effect occuring, damn it.

Comment: pretty sure OS X is a tad lighter than Windows, no clue about Linux